# VB.Net: Unable to get Standard Output from cmd Process.start over network

Tags: vb.net, networking, process.start

I'm encountering an issue with the **Process.start()** method in VB.Net.

I'm trying to execute an **ipconfig /all** and set a variable with the **StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()** method.

It works well if I execute the application locally, but when I place the EXE on a **network share**, my variable is **not set** with the result of the command.

It seems it cannot retrieve the output of the command.

Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Dim p As New Process
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
psi.Arguments = "/c ipconfig /all"
psi.UseShellExecute = False
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
p.StartInfo = psi
p.Start()
Dim output As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
p.WaitForExit()
MsgBox(output)
```

Comment: The code is not redirecting StandardError and is not checking p.ExitCode so if the command failed for some reason then you'll never know.  Once bitten twice shy, do consider using the System.Net.NetworkInformation or System.Management namespaces instead so you can get a decent exception when code fails.

Comment: @hans-passant Thank you for your answer. Effectively, I did not notice to redirect standardError, and it solve my issue. Indeed, as my executable is started from an UNC path, the cmd.exe could not be startee correctly, and was throwing an error. My problem is solved.